# how to deduplicate while keeping data in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset I'm trying to deduplicate, without losing foreign keys.

Heres the structure:

```
PK1  UUID
PK2  BIGINT
FK1  BIGINT
FK2 BIGINT
DATA1 STRING
DATA2 INTEGER
...
so forth.
```

The PKs are a combined PK.  the Two FKs come from two separate other tables.
There are duplcate rows in this table.  If PK1 and PK2 are duplicate, the Data fields
are duplicate.  The FKs are my problem.

data looks like this:

```
PK1    PK2    FK1    FK2    Data1    Data2    Data3
1      1      1      null   a        b        c
1      1      null   2      a        b        c
1      2      5      null   d        e        f
1      2      null   7      d        e        f
```

what I need is:

```
PK1    PK2    FK1    FK2    Data1    Data2    Data3
1      1      1      2      a        b        c
1      2      5      7      d        e        f
```

how can I mash these records?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT * EXCEPT(FK1_, FK2_) REPLACE(FK1_ AS FK1, FK2_ AS FK2)
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    MAX(FK1) OVER(PARTITION BY PK1, PK2) FK1_,
    MAX(FK2) OVER(PARTITION BY PK1, PK2) FK2_
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

Note: above version uses only PKi and FKi and does not aware of any other columns thus you don't need to type them all in your SELECT statement(s)

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 PK1, 1 PK2, 1 FK1, NULL FK2, 'a' Data1, 'b' Data2, 'c' Data3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, NULL, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, 5, NULL, 'd', 'e', 'f' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, NULL, 7, 'd', 'e', 'f' 
)
SELECT DISTINCT * EXCEPT(FK1_, FK2_) REPLACE(FK1_ AS FK1, FK2_ AS FK2)
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    MAX(FK1) OVER(PARTITION BY PK1, PK2) FK1_,
    MAX(FK2) OVER(PARTITION BY PK1, PK2) FK2_
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

with output

```
Row     PK1     PK2     FK1     FK2     Data1   Data2   Data3    
1       1       1       1       2       a       b       c    
2       1       2       5       7       d       e       f
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select PK1, PK2, max(FK1) as fk1, max(FK2) as fk2,
       Data1, Data2, Data3
from t
group by PK1, PK2, Data1, Data2, Data3;
```